# Why is this hello world program failing to link?

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, gcc

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
   printf("Hello, World!");
   return 0;
}
```

I installed VScode and gcc on Mac Silicon, tried running the above hello world program in C, but I get the following error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "_main", referenced from:
 implicit entry/start for main executable
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

When I run the following commands on the terminal I get this:

```
which gcc
/usr/bin/gcc

which gcc-11
/opt/homebrew/bin/gcc-11
```

I'm not sure if I installed the compiler incorrectly(first time trying C).

Comment: How exactly did you try to run the program?

Comment: Your program is (mostly) fine. How did you compile it?

Comment: I used VSCode and ran it there. It worked once, but stopped working after I tried a second time.

Answer (score -1):

For just starting out, I recommend you just have a simple task like this in `tasks.json` (Terminal -> Configure Tasks):

```
{
  "tasks": [
    {
      "label": "Run my C",
      "type": "shell",
      "command": "gcc -o myoutput ${file} && ./myoutput",
      "group": {
           "kind": "build",
           "isDefault": true
       },

      }
    }
  ],
"version": "2.0.0"
}
```

This will compile it and immediately run `./myoutput` (inside vscode's terminal). `isDefault` means that it is the default build task so you can run it by Ctrl+Shift+B (also under Terminal -> Run Build Task).